# can't import @Entity annotation from javax.persistence using Spring Data JPA

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, maven

So I'm trying to solve this problem for hours and it's really annoying.
I used Spring Initializr to generate a spring boot project: java 19, spring 3.0.0, maven, with mariadb driver, spring web, spring data jpa dependencies.
The problem is that after I create a model class, Student, I can't import @Entity annotation from javax.persistence. All the tutorials and videos I watched, they imported from javax.persistence but I got only jakarta.persistence. Why?
I tried to add myself dependency for javax.persistency but after I create the model with all annotation (@Entity, @Table, @column) the table is not created.

Here Are my files:

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>19</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mariadb.jdbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>mariadb-java-client</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Student.class

```
package com.example.demo;

import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;


@Entity(name = "student") // CAN'T GET FROM JAVAX.PERSISTENCE, SAME FOR ANNOTATIONS BELOW
public class Student {
    @Id
    @Column(name="id")
    private int id;
    @Column(name="name")
    private String name;
}
```

application.properties locates in src/main/resources

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mariadb://localhost:3307/db1
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
```

The entry point

```
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

What am I Doing wrong??

Answer (score 9):

In the newest version of Spring Boot, `javax` library is replaced by `jakarta` (see more details here https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-3.0.0-M1-Release-Notes) and here https://spring.io/blog/2022/01/20/spring-boot-3-0-0-m1-is-now-available, so it's ok that you can only find `jakarta`. You may go ahead and use it.

Answer (score 1):

javax is replaced by jakarta in letest springboot version.
Actually, the Eclipse Foundation legally had to rename Java EE. That's because Oracle has the rights over the Java brand. So to choose the new name, the community voted and picked: Jakarta EE